# PHP PDO Basic prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to do a basic prepared statement using pdo+mysql .. I can't seem to get the values assigned for the life of me :/

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=users;host=127.0.0.1', 'localAPI', 'localAPI');
 $a = 'asdf';
 $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (userName, userPass, accountStatus) VALUES (':a', ':userPass', 'unconfirmed')");
 $sth->bindParam(':a', $a, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->execute();
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!!

Table results:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+--------+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+------+
| userId | userName | userPass  | accountStatus | accountType | balance | tCreated            | tUpdated | tLastLogin | promoId | ref  |
+--------+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+------+
|      1 | :a       | :userPass | unconfirmed   | user        |       0 | 2010-12-12 13:42:10 |     NULL |       NULL |    NULL | NULL | 
+--------+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+------+
```

Comment: @Col I think the OP has simplified the question. Chances are, the values are not known constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are surrounding your variables in the SQL statement with quotes `... ':a' ..`. Remove them, as the parser would think you meant a string here, not a variable. You tell the Database that you mean a string with the `bind()` call.

Comment: Yea, I caught that just as you replied .. thanks!! /me cracks open a red bull :P

Answer (score 0):

The `var_dump` shouldn't show you a query with `:test` substituted with `123`, which seems to be what you expect. Call `$sth->execute();` and you're done.

The reason has to do with how prepared statements work. See, when a query is executed, what happens is that the query is sent as a string to the database. Here it i s parsed into an internal form, which is then executed in an interpreter. With a prepared statement, the values of variables (Such as `123` for `:test`) is transmitted and parsed separately from the query. This means that you can't "fool" the parser - which is what injection type attacks relies on - simply because the values never are part of the query and thus never reach the parser.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but the problem is that the data isn't making it to the database as it shows the parameters without being replaced. I have tested it on two servers and I don't know what could be the culprit at this point.. any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)